# Get status name by status id - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys

I have 2 classes, `ProductDetails` and `ProductStatus`.

```
class ProductDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product_status
end
```

and

```
class ProductStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_details
end
```

The schema for these tables is the following:

```
create_table "product_details", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.integer  "product_id", limit: 4
   t.string   "serial",     limit: 255
   t.string   "comment",    limit: 255
   t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
   t.integer  "status",     limit: 4
end

create_table "product_statuses", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.boolean  "available"
   t.string   "name",       limit: 255
   t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
end
```

Showing the `ProductDetails`, I have the `status_id`, but I want to display the name. It's in `product_statuses` as `name`.

I tried this:

```
<% @product_details.each do |product_detail| %>
   <td><%= product_detail.product_status.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

But It doesn't work :(

Need help.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass :(

Comment: This means that the product_id of the product_detail is either nil or is not present in the products table. Double check your database entries.

Comment: Yes, I have a product with status = 2, and this status name is "Not available". that's what are you trying to say, right?

Comment: Do i have to declare the foreign key in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I realized you're trying to use the column `status` as foreign key. This has to be mentioned in the belongs_to statement:

```
 belongs_to :product_status, foreign_key: :status
```

By default, rails is looking for a column named `product_status_id` as foreign key.

See also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key

Comment: Lol, that's it. TYVM!